Unexpected behaviour in slider's elements with different heights
I have three sections of weather: current weather, 1-day forecast, and finally, 5-day forecast, all sharing the same class weather section but supposed to have different heights.
I added a slide animation effect to the sections that trigger when the user clicks the corresponding tab.
However, the next slide goes under or on top of the previous one while animating. It takes its normal position only after the animation finishes, as in this example, the ond-day forecast goes under the current weather section and takes its normal position only after the animation ends:



let selectedWeatherSection = 1;
let isFetching = false;

const currentWeatherLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="current-weather"]');

const oneDayForecastLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="one-day-forecast"]');

const fiveDayForecastLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="five-days-forecast"]');

function afterNextRepaint(callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== 'function')
        return;

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            callback();
        });
    });
}

function showWeatherSection(n) {
    if (isFetching || selectedWeatherSection === n) // Stop the animation
        return;

    const weatherSections = document.querySelectorAll("main div.container section.weather-section");
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll("main div.container div.weather-tab div.wrapper label");
    const tempIndex = selectedWeatherSection;

    tabs[selectedWeatherSection - 1].classList.remove("active");

    if (n > weatherSections.length)
        selectedWeatherSection = 1;
    else if (n < 1)
        selectedWeatherSection = weatherSections.length;
    else
        selectedWeatherSection = n;

    isFetching = true;

    const activeWeatherSection = document.querySelector("main div.container section.weather-section.active");
    const nextSection = weatherSections[selectedWeatherSection - 1];
    const nextTab = tabs[selectedWeatherSection - 1];

    if (n > tempIndex) {
        nextSection.classList.add("next");

        afterNextRepaint(() => {
            activeWeatherSection.classList.add("left");
            nextSection.classList.add("left");
        });

        nextSection.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                nextSection.classList.add("active");

                activeWeatherSection.classList.remove("left");
                activeWeatherSection.classList.remove("active");

                nextSection.classList.remove("next");
                nextSection.classList.remove("left");

                isFetching = false;
            },
            {once: true}
        );
    } else {
        nextSection.classList.add("prev");

        afterNextRepaint(() => {
            activeWeatherSection.classList.add("right");
            nextSection.classList.add("right");
        });

        nextSection.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                nextSection.classList.add("active");

                activeWeatherSection.classList.remove("right");
                activeWeatherSection.classList.remove("active");

                nextSection.classList.remove("prev");
                nextSection.classList.remove("right");

                isFetching = false;
            },
            {once: true}
        );
    }
    nextTab.classList.add("active");
}

const downloadForecast = (forecastDuration, forecastLink) => {
    if (isFetching)
        return

    if (forecastDuration === "one-day")
        showWeatherSection(2);
    else if (forecastDuration === "five-days")
        showWeatherSection(3)

  // some AJAX resuests..
}

currentWeatherLabel.addEventListener('click', () =>
    showWeatherSection(1)
);

oneDayForecastLabel.addEventListener('click', () =>
    downloadForecast("one-day", "./weather/one-day-forecast")
);

fiveDayForecastLabel.addEventListener('click', () =>
    downloadForecast("five-days", "./weather/five-days-forecast")
);
main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: #DCDCDD;
}

main div.container {
    max-width: 1266px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #DCDCDD;
}

main div.container > section.weather-section {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 1.5s ease-in-out left;
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.next,
main div.container > section.weather-section.prev {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.next {
    left: 100%
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.prev {
    left: -100%
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.next.left,
main div.container > section.weather-section.prev.right {
    left: 0
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.active.left {
    left: -100%
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.active.right {
    left: 100%
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.active {
    left: 0;
}

main div.container > section.weather-section.active,
main div.container > section.weather-section.next,
main div.container > section.weather-section.prev {
    display: block;
}

.today-weather {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 23px 0;
}

.today-weather h2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.today-current-weather {
    display: flex;
    width: 65%;
}

.today-current-weather div {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.current-condition div {
    height: 114px;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.current-condition-icon img {
    height: 132px;
    width: 144px;
}

.current-highlight {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.current-highlight h2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

div.weather-info {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.weather-card {
    position: relative;
    background: #f7f7ff;
    width: 30%;
    height: 222px;
    margin: 19px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* make child items grow/shrink vertically */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    animation-name: card-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.weather-card span.weather-card-title {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #60656F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.weather-card div.weather-card-information {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-top: 14%;
    height: calc(100% - 20%);
}

div.humidity, div.wind, div.real-temperature-data, div.visibility, div.real-temperature-shade {
    display: flex;
}

.wind-data {
    width: 100%;
}

.wind-data > div {
    height: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 35px);
}

.humidity-data, .wind-data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.humidity-data, .humidity-indicator {
    width: 50%;
}

.humidity-data-percentage, .humidity-data-description {
    height: 50%;
}

.wind-speed, .wind-direction {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.visibility, .visibility-data {
    height: 100%;
}

.visibility-data-percentage, .visibility-data-description {
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
}

.weather-card div.weather-card-information.uv-index {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


@keyframes card-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.weather-tab {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 55vw;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.wrapper nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper nav label {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper nav label a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    color: #1d1f20;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.6s ease;
}

.wrapper nav #home:checked ~ label.current-weather a,
.wrapper nav #inbox:checked ~ label.one-day-forecast a,
.wrapper nav #contact:checked ~ label.five-days-forecast a {
    color: #fff;
}

.wrapper nav label a i {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 7px;
}

.wrapper nav .tab {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.33%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.wrapper nav label[for="current-weather"].active ~ .tab {
    left: 0;
}

.wrapper nav label[for="one-day-forecast"].active ~ .tab {
    left: 33.33%;
}

.wrapper nav label[for="five-days-forecast"].active ~ .tab {
    left: 66.66%;
}

.wrapper nav input {
    display: none;
}
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="weather-tab">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav>
                    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="current-weather" checked>
                    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="one-day-forecast">
                    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="five-days-forecast">

                    <label for="current-weather" class="weather-tab active">
                        <a href="#">Current weather</a>
                    </label>

                    <label for="one-day-forecast" class="weather-tab">
                        <a href="#">One day forecast</a>
                    </label>

                    <label for="five-days-forecast" class="weather-tab">
                        <a href="#">Five days forecast</a>
                    </label>

                    <div class="tab"></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section id="current-weather" class="weather-section active">
            <section class="today-weather">
                <h2>Current Condition</h2>

                <div class="today-current-weather">
                    <div class="current-condition">
                        <div class="weather-card">
                            <div class="current-condition-icon"><img alt="weather-icon" src=""></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="weather-card">
                            <div class="current-condition-temperature">20</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="current-condition">
                        <div class="weather-card">
                            <div class="current-condition-time">2024/12/05</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="weather-card">
                            <div class="current-condition-temperature">Good</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="current-highlight">
                <h2>Current highlight</h2>

                <div class="weather-info">
                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">UV index</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information uv-index">
                            <uv-index value={{uvIndex}}></uv-index>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">Wind status</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information">
                            <div class="wind">
                                <div class="wind-data">
                                    <div class="wind-speed">
                                        <img src="./images/icons/wind-icon.gif" style="height: 15px;width: 15px" alt="">
                                        150 Km/h
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wind-direction">30° w</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">Feels like</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information">
                            <div class="real-temperature-data">
                                <div class="weather-card-information">25</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">Humidity</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information">
                            <div class="humidity">
                                <div class="humidity-data">
                                    <div class="humidity-data-percentage">60</div>
                                    <div class="humidity-data-description">OK</div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="humidity-indicator">
                                    <humidity-percentage value={{humidity}}></humidity-percentage>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">Visibility</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information">
                            <div class="visibility">
                                <div class="visibility-data">
                                    <div class="visibility-data-percentage">55 Km</div>
                                    <div class="visibility-data-description">55</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="weather-card">
                        <span class="weather-card-title">Temperature in shade</span>

                        <div class="weather-card-information">
                            <div class="real-temperature-shade">
                                <div class="real-temperature-shade-data">
                                    <div class="weather-card-information">30</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section id="one-day-forecast" class="weather-section">
            <h1>One day forecast</h1>
        </section>

        <section id="five-days-forecast" class="weather-section">
            <h1>Five days forecast</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>



I would like to know why this is happening and how I can fix it

This happens because the "one-day-forecast" e "five-days-forecast" sections don't have anything insed them. The "current-weather" only appears bigger cause it have something inside.
To avoid the last two sections appears so small you can set a height to them and be sure that this will appear big having or haven't some child inside.
You can set something like this in your css. This you ensure that your sections will be at least 100% of your viewport height


#today-weather, #one-day-forecast, #five-days-forecast {
  min-height: 100vh;
}



